# When can a final exe have a different name than the solution name in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, visual-studio-2003

I am having to look after a big solution created in Visual Studio 2003 using MFC and C++
I opened and converted it into VC2010 version using Visual Studio 2010 Professional
The solution name, the vc project file name, etc are all called telemetry and I am building for a final release version. But the exe file in the release folder shows up in a different name. When I try to run the file from the IDE using the green run button, it gives an error saying Telemetry.exe not found in the release folder. However I have cleaned and rebuilt the solution many times, but the exe file shows up under a different name
The person who used to maintain the code before had told me that it doesn't build at all under VS2010 . I am not sure what he ment, but I did not have any problems building it. The only problem seems to be running it from the IDE after build, which is due to the exe filename being different than the solution filename.

What settings may be causing the exe filename to be different than the solution name?

---

### EDIT FOR NEW QUESTION IN COMMENT

Error:
[image]
Settings in Visual Studio:
[image]

Comment: `Project Properties->Linker->General->Output File` or `Project Properties->General->Target Name`.

Comment: Project properties > configuration properties > general > target name has ($ProjectName)

Comment: Yes, that's the default - the exe will be named the same as the project. What does the linker option say?

Comment: ok I just found the linker option and it does indeed have the new exe file name. This must be where the exe fie gets it's name from

Comment: ok that explained a lot. Thank you very much. If you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: After building solution, if I click the green triangle in the IDE to run the compiled file, I get the error shown above, while my IDE settings are shown. Why does Run command in the IDE still look for Telemetry.exe?

Comment: Also, what is that `.` before `\Release`? There was `.\Release/EasyFit.exe` in the Output File option previously, and this error used to occur. So I deleted the `.` from the Output File, but I am still getting this error. Why is that?

Comment: Just drop-down the combo in that option and select "Inherit from parent or project defaults", you'll get what you want.

Comment: Actually I want the output to remain EasyFit.exe, I don't want it to become Telemetry, even though I want to keep the project name still at Telemetry.

Comment: Well, the ".\" is just a way of saying "relative to current folder", so the exe went in the Release folder of the solution. Maybe you need to check `Project Properties->Debugging->Command` to see what it tries to run when you hit F5.

Comment: Project Properties->Debugging->Command is set to $(TargetPath) and it looks like it's value changes as I fiddle around with other options. $(TargetPath) seems to contain the path shown in the error message above, that is, a `.` between the folders as if the `.` itself is a folder name

Comment: Maybe your best option is to change `Target Name` in `General` and reset everything else to defaults.

Comment: ok it's runnig now. I am still getting some error related to debug information not being present, but it's probably because I have chosen Release build instead of debug build. Anyway the exe is running from the IDE as well. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not been changed in  `Project Properties->General->Target Name`, which defaults to `($ProjectName)`, look at `Project Properties->Linker->General->Output File` to see if a specific name has been requested for the linker output.